# How can i use a memcached client to search key value pairs?? which memcached client is better -- (spymemcached, xmemcached or gwhalin)??

Tags: java, memcached

How can i use a memcached client to **search** key value pairs?? what if my key is a composite key?? A single *threaded client* or *multiThreaded client* is useful??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. Memcached hashes the key using some algorithm that distributes keys randomly. This makes key based searching unlikely

Comment: distributes the keys randomly on what?? different servers???  I am using only single server on my machine(localhost)..  can u elaborate more?? what about searching on single server(localhost)..

Comment: Well, `randomly` more applies to a cluster of memcached servers. Memcached does not store you plaintext key but it creates a hash of that string using some algorithm and stores you values against this hash.